# How to print sha256 hash in Rust? (GenericArray)

Tags: rust

I'm testing the sha2 crate (https://docs.rs/sha2/0.9.3/sha2/)

```
let base2: i32 = 2;
let total_size = base2.pow(24);
let mut data = vec![0u8;total_size as usize];
let mut hasher = Sha256::new();
hasher.update(data);
let result = hasher.finalize();
println!("sha256 before write: {}", result);
```

however I cannot print the result:

```
error[E0277]: `GenericArray<u8, UInt<UInt<UInt<UInt<UInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>, B0>, B0>, B0>, B0>, B0>>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> src/sha_check.rs:60:41
   |
60 |     println!("sha256 before write: {}", result);
   |                                         ^^^^^^ `GenericArray<u8, UInt<UInt<UInt<UInt<UInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>, B0>, B0>, B0>, B0>, B0>>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
```

How can I dump a `GenericArray`?

I tried finding `.finalize()` but I don't know where it comes from.

Comment: SHA256 produces a sequence of raw bytes, and you're trying to print them to a (text) terminal. What do you expect to see on screen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`GenericArray`](https://docs.rs/generic-array/0.14.4/generic_array/struct.GenericArray.html) implements `LowerHex` and `UpperHex`. So you can do either:

```
println!("sha256 before write: {:x}", result);
```

```
sha256 before write: 080acf35a507ac9849cfcba47dc2ad83e01b75663a516279c8b9d243b719643e
```

or

```
println!("sha256 before write: {:X}", result);
```

```
sha256 before write: 080ACF35A507AC9849CFCBA47DC2AD83E01B75663A516279C8B9D243B719643E
```