# How to get a hex string from Rust's MD-5 (MD5) crate?

Tags: rust, cryptography, md5

According to this RFC about WWW Authentication (used in HTTTP) https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#page-7,

> For the purposes of this document, an MD5 digest of 128 bits is
> represented as 32 ASCII printable characters. The bits in the 128 bit
> digest are converted from most significant to least significant bit,
> four bits at a time to their ASCII presentation as follows. Each four
> bits is represented by its familiar hexadecimal notation from the
> characters 0123456789abcdef. That is, binary 0000 gets represented by
> the character '0', 0001, by '1', and so on up to the representation
> of 1111 as 'f'.

Rust's [MD5 crate](https://crates.io/crates/md-5) implements the Digest trait: https://docs.rs/digest/0.9.0/digest/trait.Digest.html which digests to a GenericArray which consists of `8` 16-bit slices.

How do I convert for this hash format from RFC? Why doesn't the md-5 crate has a simple feature that displays the digest as hexadecimal values?

The crate `literal_hex` does the opposite: converts from String of hexadecimal concatenated values to bytes.

Comment: Judging from the docs on Digest you can convert to a hex string easily using `format!("{:x}", md5::Md5::digest(b"Hello world"));` - does that not work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print sha256 hash in Rust? (GenericArray)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66728572/how-to-print-sha256-hash-in-rust-genericarray)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I convert for this hash format from RFC?

Format it using [the `x` (LowerHex) format specifier](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.LowerHex.html):

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = md5::Md5::new();
    println!("{:x}", s.finalize());
    // d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
    println!("{:x}", md5::Md5::digest(b""));
    // d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
}
```

as [the example for `digest::Digest::digest` shows](https://docs.rs/digest/0.9.0/digest/trait.Digest.html#tymethod.digest).

> Why doesn't the md-5 crate has a simple feature that displays the digest as hexadecimal values?

Because that's built into Rust.